# Как вернуть массив структур в функции int?

Tags: c#

В начале у меня есть структура Airplane. мне нужно (вне структуры) объявить массив и написать функцию, которая читает с клавиатуры массив структур (n штук) и возвращает массив структур типа Airplane и вызвать эту функцию в void menu(). Компилятор на меня матюкается..

```
class Program
{
    Airplane[] arr;
    static void menu()
    {
        int q;
        WriteLine("Что вы хотите сделать?? ");
        do {
            q = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            switch (q)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        
                        //arr = vvod(arr);
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        arr = ReadAirplaneArray(arr);//тут компилятор пишет ошибку (пишет "Требуется ссылка на объект")
                        break;
                    }
            }



        } while (q != 0);
        

    }
    static int ReadAirplaneArray(Airplane [] arr)
    {
        int n;
        WriteLine("Сколько рейсов вы хотите ввести? ");
        n = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        arr = new Airplane[n];

        return arr;// и ещё вот тут вот тоже подчёркивает красным
    }

  
}
```

Comment: функция int может вернуть только int и ничего более.

Comment: ок, меняю int на тип данных Airplane. Это абсолютно ничегошеньки не поменяло.

Comment: конечно, ведь Airplane и Airplane[] - это разные типы.

Comment: вот,  теперь заработало. Спасибо!!

Comment: Я откатил состояние вопроса к изначальному варианту.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я понял, у вас передозировка С++ и вы хотите вернуть указатель из метода, в C# это так не работает, а работает вот как:

Чтобы создать массив и присвоить его значение вне метода, из метода, то можно передавать его по ссылке `ref`

```cs
static void ReadAirplaneArraySize(ref Airplane[] arr)
{
    WriteLine("Сколько рейсов вы хотите ввести? ");
    int n = int.Parse(ReadLine());
    arr = new Airplane[n];
}
```

Ну и вот так использовать

```cs
ReadAirplaneArraySize(ref arr);
```

И так как методы ваши статичны, нужно либо их сделать нестатичными, либо массив сделать статичным.

```cs
static Airplane[] arr;
```

Или даже лучше, так как у вас уже массив передается как аргумент, можно его объявить внутри метода, а не в статичном поле

```cs
static void menu()
{
    Airplane[] arr = null;
    // ваш код
}
```

Comment: Теперь не хочет вызывать функцию ReadAirplaneArray(ref arr);

Comment: @МихаилОргиш еще раз дополнил ответ. Важно, лучше внесите массив внутрь метода.